# Should we favor Vector drawable over multiple densities drawable?

Tags: android

It is common that we provides various densities drawables in the project

```
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

I was wondering, should we favor Vector drawable over multiple densities drawable?

I went through https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#vector-graphics .

But, it doesn't mention when should we use multiple densities drawable, and when should we use Vector drawable. Is there any situation when Vector drawable is not favorable?

Comment: it is always good to use vector drawables over multiple densities. But at some places they do have limitations but in future I believe it will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Vector drawables should always be favoured where it is possible to replace the image with a vector as it is completely scalable.

The only place where you would use an image with different densities is when the image cannot be represented by a vector drawable.

Comment: Is there any official guideline on this? Is Vector method guarantee to work across all devices and all version?

Comment: Is the official documentation not enough? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources
Another definite advantage is the size of the vector's xml file.
Also, there is a number of articles describing benefits of using vectors, just ask google https://medium.com/the-android-guy/stop-using-pngs-use-vector-drawable-why-8ca68bed5335

Comment: Well vector drawables have some limitations, it can not render gradients only sollid colors. You also have to know that Android 4 versions devices might crash by using vector drawable wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#vector-graphics):

> An alternative to creating multiple density-specific versions of an image is to create just one vector graphic. Vector graphics create an image using XML to define paths and colors, instead of using pixel bitmaps. As such, vector graphics can scale to any size without scaling artifacts, though they're usually best for illustrations such as icons, not photographs.

So vector drawables are always a better choice then using multiple densities.

This documentation will help you further:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources

Answer (score 1):

Vector drawables are natively supported in API 21 and up (Android 5) and you won't need to use any special library to be able to use them in your app. For example in the Image tag you can use the `src` attribute to load vectors just as you would use them to load bitmap images.

They can also be used in older versions of Android with the help of Google support library but there will be a big performance hit.